# jQuery FadeOut() function not doing anything in FF

Tags: jquery, fade

I have the following HTML for a wedding RSVP site I'm building:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Amy and Scott's Wedding - RSVP Page</title>
        <link href="http://www.asjwedding.com/style/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://www.asjwedding.com/style/user.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.asjwedding.com/script/formControl.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="doc">
            <div id="content">
                <div class="text-content">
                    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
                    <div class="question">
                        ... omitted for brevity ...
                                        <div id="messageArea" class="response">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="submitButton">
                      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validateForm();">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And, I have the following javascript using jQuery:

```
function hideMessage() {
  alert("Fading...");
  $("#messageArea").fadeOut();
}
```

But, the fading isn't working for some reason, and I'm not sure why. If I do a hide() inside of hideMessage(), it works fine, but if I use fadeOut(), nothing happens. (Actually, that's not true... it does give me the alert, but it doesn't actually do the fading).

I'm using Firefox Nightly (14.0) on Linux, but Firefox Nightly on Android actually **does** work... I'm not entirely sure why it's not working on desktop.

Can someone assist me?

**EDIT**:

Some code from the other javascript functions I have:

```
function validateForm() {
  // Verify at least one of the rsvp options is selected.
  if (!$("#radNone").attr("checked") &&
      !$("#radWedding").attr("checked") &&
      !$("#radReception").attr("checked") &&
      !$("#radBoth").attr("checked")) {
     sendMessage("Please choose one of the RSVP options.");
        return;
  }
}

function hideMessage() {
  alert("Fading...");
  $("#messageArea").fadeOut();
}

function sendNegativeMessage(message) {
  $("#messageArea").css('background-color', '#FF6666');
  $("#messageArea").html(message);
  $("#messageArea").show();
}

function sendMessage(message, type) {
  setTimeout(hideMessage, 1000);

  $('#messageArea').css('opacity', '1.0');
  // Type can be 'positive', 'negative.
  if (!type) {
    // Assume it's negative.
    sendNegativeMessage(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: When do you want this fade to occur on page load, on button click?

Comment: @Wyck, I don't think that will create a difference.

Comment: It won't, but knowing how he invokes is it very important. I can see the `validateForm()` function being called, but I don't see the `validateForm()` and if it's calling the `hideMessage()` function or not.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/MVAGD/2/ And let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Exactly, and also if he wanted an answer with a working example.

Comment: I should clarify a bit. I'm using Firefox nightly. it works fine on mobile, but not on desktop. I am calling the hide function directly from the js console. I am also calling it from a set timeout call timeout call. validate sets up the set timeout call and  shows the message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure it's being called after the DOM is loaded (otherwise the alert will correctly fire, but the DOM element won't exist, leading to problems when you attempt to manipulate it). Try this:

```
function hideMessage() {
    alert("Fading...");
        $("#messageArea").fadeOut();
    }

$(function() {
    hideMessage();
});
```

Comment: it's being called well after the Dom loads... it's called from a submit button

Comment: hi jwir3, could you post some of your `validateForm()` so we can see what is going on?

Comment: sure, just give me a bit to get back to my computer. I'm on a mobile device right now.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... strange, but now it appears to be working just fine. I actually haven't changed anything (I know that people say things like that, but in this case, even the timestamps of the files are from before I asked the question).

I must have been looking at an old version of the site... or something...